# What actually happens when you touch the screen on pokemon go?

Tags: pokemon-go

When you are on the GPS screen, showing the roads and that etc. you can tap any where on the screen and a blue ring appears with a strange noise at the same time, what does this actually mean? has it got anything to do with locating/revealing Pokemon or the leaves that move about occasionally?

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing significant, it's just a graphic animation on the user end, to confirm that you tapped here. Indeed, when you tap and nothing appears you can assume that your session is bugged and that you have to relaunch the game. It's a feedback.